# What's the proper name for this pectoral muscles movement?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

What's the proper name for this pectoral muscles movement:

[image]

Not to be confused with *pec bounce*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124001/discussion-on-question-by-matt-pelvin-whats-the-proper-name-for-this-pectoral-m).

Answer (score 0):

The model is contracting his chest muscles and so the movement is called "contraction".

> - [contraction](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contraction)  the shortening and thickening of a functioning muscle or muscle fiber

From the web:

[1](https://www.plasticsurgeonnewportbeach.com/before-after-breast-photos/orange-county-male-breast-reduction/patient-14/). "He was unhappy with nipple areola protrusion especially when contracting his chest muscles."

[2](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=kOVgBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT164&lpg=PT164&dq=%22contracting+his+chest+muscles%22&source=bl&ots=DbMoHXhhAR&sig=ACfU3U2gHLVvU2zSDFZro-dvD-w9qetGGA&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_h_u-0JfwAhV6r5UCHYSOAYoQ6AEwEXoECBUQAw#v=onepage&q=%22contracting%20his%20chest%20muscles%22&f=false). "Bill Penn charges up the ramp with his arms upraised, contracting his chest muscles and biceps like a steroid-addled bodybuilder."